# React JS - How to add value from state to specific element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*Hey guys, i am working on a germany game called Kniffel. Its basically dice game.*

So I am currently saving final score from thrown dice as State.

And then i would like to take that score from state and when i click a button it will save the score to specific element.

You can imagine it more when you check the code.

```
/* SAVING A SCORE TO STATE */
    const [totalValue, setTotalValue] = React.useState(0)
   /* HOW I GET IT */
    let total = 0

    React.useEffect(() => {

    dice.map(die => {
     if (die.isHeld) {
     total += die.value
    }

    })
    setTotalValue(total)
    }, [dice])
```

And i would like every time i click a button, the score from totalValue will pass to P element, where the button is located. Then a game is going to restart and next round you pass the score to different element.

There will me multiple score--inside divs, so i am thinking how should i approach this. Any help will be GOD!

if you guys have any ideas, let me know please.

**UPDATE**

I little bit change a code and made a another state with multiple scores:

```
// TOTAL
  const [totalValue, setTotalValue] = React.useState()

// TOTALS
const [totalValues, setTotalValues] = React.useState({
  ER1: 0,
  ER2: 0,
  ER3: 0,
  ER4: 0,
  ER5: 0,
  ER6: 0,
  Dreier: 0,
  Vierer: 0,
  Full: 0,
  Kleine: 0,
  Grobe: 0,
  Kniffel: 0,
  Chance: 0
})
```

Then i made a multiple functions, that will update the array.

```
function er1() {
  setTotalValues(prevState => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      ER1: totalValue
    }
  })
}

function er2() {
  setTotalValues(prevState => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      ER2: totalValue
    }
  })
}

function er3() {
  setTotalValues(prevState => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      ER3: totalValue
    }
  })
}

.......etc
```

passing functions as props and passing them to buttons:

```
export default function Score({Score, Next, Values, er1, er2, er3}) {
    return (
        <div className="score--box">
        
            <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>1ER:</h3>
                <p>{Values.ER1}</p>
                <button onClick={() => {er1();Next()}}>Add score</button>
            </div>
        
    
            <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>2ER:</h3>
                <p>{Values.ER2}</p>
                <button onClick={() => {er2();Next()}}>Add score</button>
            </div>
            <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>3ER:</h3>
                <p>{Values.ER3}</p>
                <button onClick={() => {er3();Next()}}>Add score</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When i look up to this, it will work but its not efficient how i would like it. Any idea how to simplify this?

Comment: You can display a value in the markup like this: `<p>{props.Score}</p>`  But overall the question sounds like you just have an idea of something you want to build and are asking for general help to build it, which is [too broad to be meaningfully answered here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193).  You are encouraged to walk through some React tutorials and attempt to start building your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can keep multi numbers it should better keep in an object instead number

```
const [totalValues, setTotalValue] = React.useState({})

and only one method can handle all objects
onClick=({target})=>{
totalValues[target.name]=target.value;
}
```

it just needs your element name to be an identity

```js
return (
        <div className="score--box">
            <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>1ER:</h3>
                <p></p>
                <button onClick={onClick} name='1ER'>Add score</button>
            </div>
            <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>2ER:</h3>
                <p></p>
                <button onClick={onClick} name='2ER'>Add score</button>
            </div>
            <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>3ER:</h3>
                <p></p>
                <button onClick={onClick} name='3ER'>Add score</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
```

Finally you have this object {1ER:4,2ER:5,3ER:2,...}

> **this a sample**

```js
export const Score = () => {
  const [totalValues, setTotalValue] = useState({})
  const onClick = ({ target }) => {
    let randomScore = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    totalValues[target.name] = randomScore;
    setTotalValue({...totalValues});
  }
  return (
    <div >
      <Label>{totalValues['2ER']}</Label>
      <div className="score--inside">
        <h3>1ER:</h3>
        <p>{totalValues.ER1}</p>
        <button onClick={onClick} name='ER1'>Add score</button>
      </div>
      <div className="score--inside">
        <h3>2ER:</h3>
        <p>{totalValues['ER2']}</p>
        <button onClick={onClick} name='ER2'>Add score</button>
      </div>
      <div className="score--inside">
        <h3>3ER:</h3>
        <p>{totalValues['ER3']}</p>
        <button onClick={onClick} name='ER3'>Add score</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where exactly you put your onClick function?

Comment: if tell me how to get a score I can help more.
it's coming from props?

Comment: Ye score is coming from props as state. I am basically counting score every time dice change. 



let total = 0

React.useEffect(() => {

dice.map(die => {
  if (die.isHeld) {
    total += die.value
  }

})
setTotalValue(total)
}, [dice])

Comment: I have written a sample for you

Answer (score 1):

You can have a state like `passTo` inside the score component. Then add a button click event listener that identifies the button clicked. You can selectively display value of `Score` inside correct `<p>` with condition

```
// import useState
export default function Score({Score}) {

 const [passTo, setPassTo] = useState()

const handleClick = (btnId) => {
   setPassTo(btnId);
}

    return (
        <div className="score--box">
            <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>1ER:</h3>
                <p>{passTo==='1ER' && Score}</p>
                <button onClick={() => handleClick('1ER')}>Add score</button>
            </div>
            <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>2ER:</h3>
                <p>{passTo==='2ER' && Score}</p>
                <button onClick={() => handleClick('2ER')}>Add score</button>
            </div>
            <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>3ER:</h3>
                <p>{passTo==='3ER' && Score}</p>
                <button onClick={() => handleClick('3ER')}>Add score</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
```

To further simplify, if there would be multiple scores like '1ER', '2ER' etc, , you can put those in an array and map through that

```
   // import useState
    export default function Score({Score}) {
       const scoreArr = ['1ER', '2ER', '3ER'] //As many needed, can pass as props too.
       const [passTo, setPassTo] = useState()
       
        const handleClick = (btnId) => {
           setPassTo(btnId);
        }
        return (
                <div className="score--box">
                     <div className="score--box">
                          {scoreArr.map((score) => {
                                  return ( 
                                  <div className="score--inside">
                                     <h3>`${score}:`</h3>
                                     <p>{passTo===score && Score} 
                                               </p>
                                     <button onClick={() => handleClick(score)}>Add score</button>
                                  </div>);
                   })}
               </div>
                </div>
                )
            }
```

Lemme know if it helps :)

Comment: It works great, thanks. Just trying to figure out, when the Score state reset, the score inside element reset too, and i need to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a ScoreContainder component which contains the button and the `<p></p>` element

```
   export default function Score({id, score, setSelectedId, selectedId}){
       const onClick = ()=>{
           setSelectedId(id)
       }
       return <div className="score--inside">
                <h3>1ER:</h3>
                <p>{id===selectedId && score}</p>
                <button onClick={onClick} name='1ER'>Add score</button>
            </div>
   }
```

and in the parent component return this

```
     export const Parent(){
         const [totalValue, setTotalValue] = React.useState(0)
         const scoreRef = React.useRef(0)
         const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = React.useState()
         const getRandomnumber = ()=>{ // this causes rerender  
             scoreRef.current = Math.random() //or any other random funtion
             setTotalValue(scoreRef.current) 
         }
         const reset = ()=>{scoreRef.current = 0} //this won't cause rerender and reset the score value without showing the changes on the screen 
         return <div className="score--box">
             <Score id={0} score={totoalValue} selectedId={selectedId} setSelectedId = {setSelectedId}/>   
             <Score id={1} score={totoalValue} selectedId={selectedId} setSelectedId = {setSelectedId}/>
             <Score id={2} score={totoalValue} selectedId={selectedId} setSelectedId = {setSelectedId}/>
         
         </div>
     }
```

Comment: It works great, thanks. Just trying to figure out, when the Score state reset, the score inside element reset too, and i need to prevent that.

Comment: then you have to have two variables one is a state that causes rerendering and one with useRef that doesn't causes rerender

Comment: I change the code so can you check it now